# Redirecting to Login page on Ajax Post Request when spring Security is Enable for ajax URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have Implemented Spring-Security in my WebApp and when I click on LIKE button it sends an ajax request to the SERVER

(My URL is: `http:localhost:8080/myWebApp/likes/qs/10)`

my spring security configuration for this URL is

```
<http>  
<!-- Admin access Only -->
<intercept-url pattern="/manage/**" access="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" /> 
<!-- FOR USER -->
<intercept-url pattern="/likes/**" access="hasAuthority('USER')" method="POST"/> 
</http>
```

When the URL changes in the browser(first case) it redirect the user to the Login page. (works fine)
 but in case of ajax request, the URL is restricted to post on the server although it does not redirect to login Page if the user is not logged In..

```
General
Request URL: http:localhost:8080/myWebApp/likes/qs/10
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Resonse Header
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2019 07:09:37 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: http://localhost:8080/eveprep/login
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Header
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: JSESSIONID=54E50C4CE1E32BD2FFDA60B6AE2992B9
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/eveprep/show/subCategory/1/mcqs/1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 08599de2-8fb5-41c6-83dc-a4d034933a42
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

js file

```
$('body').on('click','.likebtn',function(event) {
    var btn = $(this);
    var likeBtnId = btn.prop('id');
    var likeUrl = window.contextRoot+ '/likes/qs/'+ likeBtnId;                  
        $.post(likeUrl,function(data) {
            Swal.fire({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Unliked',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
            })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, **you can't redirect user in ajax requests**. One possible solution can be something like this:

1. Set an id for your login form. For example `<form id="#loginForm">`
2. In the success callback of your ajax request, parse the result, if contains `#loginForm` word, it means, user is not authenticated and spring redirects him to login page after accessing a protected url. Then you can redirect him to your login page with javascript `window.location`.

**Note:** Parsing ajax result in every ajax request is very hard and also needs to many code changes. Instead, you can set success event handler for all ajax requests once and globally with [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/). With this method, you don't need to modify ajax call methods.

Comment: I have tried this but it always redirect to login pag( also in case when user is logedIn)         ````var formID = $(this).parents("form").attr("id");
        if ( formID = "loginForm" )
        {
         window.location = '/eveprep/login'
        }````